# Replace space with a + sign

Tags: php, html

I have a problem, after sending information(a string)  through a link I want to replace the space in the string with a + sign, this is what I have done

html:

```
<a href="script.php?name=Eri+Son">send</a>
```

Script:

```
 $name = $_GET['name'];
    str_replace(" ", "+", $name);
    echo $name;

result: Eri Son
```

Comment: Look into urldecode/(raw)urlencode

Comment: You can use %20, instead of a +, in the URL, that will give a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send the literal `+` as a query string parameter, you must urlencode it:

```
<a href="script.php?name=<?php echo urlencode('Eri+Son'); ?>">send</a>
```

Result:

```
<a href="script.php?name=Eri%2BSon">send</a>
```

On server side, `$_GET[name]` will contain `Eri+Son`. The other answers as well as your idea of doing a str_replace on query string parameters is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You're not assigning value returned by `str_replace` to the `$name` variable. Try:

`$name = str_replace(" ", "+", $name);`

Comment: You explain the error good. But for urls better use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo preg_replace(' ', '+', $name);
```